# How to find employee by id with textbox and button

Tags: c#, button, textbox

My question is how can I find employee by his ID for example if I type in textbox 17432 and when I click on search button its should give me employee id fullname lastname and salary information .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_employee
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Employee[] employee = new Employee[10];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            employee[0] = new Employee(17432, "john", "Adverd", 800.00);
            employee[1] = new Employee(17433, "Adrian", "Smith", 800.00);
            employee[2] = new Employee(17434, "Stephen", "Rad", 9000.00);
            employee[3] = new Employee(17435, "Jesse", "Harris", 800.00);
            employee[4] = new Employee(17436, "jonatan", "Morris", 9500.00);
            employee[5] = new Employee(17437, "Morgen", "Freeman", 12000.00);
            employee[6] = new Employee(17438, "Leory", "Gomez", 10200.00);
            employee[7] = new Employee(17439, "Michael", "Brown", 9000.00);
            employee[8] = new Employee(17440, "Andrew", "White", 3500.00);
            employee[9] = new Employee(17441, "Maria", "Carson", 17000.00);
        }

        private void Searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string employeeString = employee[i].employeeInformationToString() + "\r\n";

                listBox1.Items.Add(employeeString);

            }

        }
        public void Lowestemployeesalary()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            double Minimumsal = employee[0].Salary;
            for(int i = 0; i < employee.Count(); i++)
            {
                if(Minimumsal > employee[i].Salary )
                {
                    Minimumsal = employee[i].Salary;
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < employee.Count(); j++)
            {
                if(Minimumsal == employee[j].Salary)
                {
                    string result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", employee[j].EmployeeIDNum, employee[j].FullName, employee[j].LastName, employee[j].Salary);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }
        public void Highemployeesalary()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            double Mixsal = employee[0].Salary;
            for (int i = 0; i < employee.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (Mixsal < employee[i].Salary)
                {
                    Mixsal = employee[i].Salary;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < employee.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (Mixsal == employee[j].Salary)
                {
                    string result = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", employee[j].EmployeeIDNum, employee[j].FullName, employee[j].LastName, employee[j].Salary);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }
        private void getinfibtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lowestemployeesalary();
        }
        private void highestbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Highemployeesalary();
        }

        private void sreachbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //// Need Some Thing Here
        }
    }
}
```

And Here is my Class Employee

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_employee
{
    class Employee
    {
        private int employeeID;
        private string fullName;
        private string lastName;
        private double salary;
        public Employee()
        {
            employeeID = 0;
            fullName = "";
            lastName = "";
            salary = 0.0;
        }
        public Employee(int empIDValue, string fullNameVal, string lastNameVal)
        {
            employeeID = empIDValue;
            fullName = fullNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            salary = 0.0;
        }
        public Employee(int empIDValue, string fullNameVal, string lastNameVal, double salaryValue)
        {
            employeeID = empIDValue;
            fullName = fullNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            salary = salaryValue;
        }
        public int EmployeeIDNum
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeID = value;
            }
        }
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return fullName;
            }
            set
            {
                fullName = value;

            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;

            }
        }
        public double Salary
        {
            get
            {
                return salary;
            }
            set
            {
                salary = value;
            }
        }
        public int Getinfo
        {
            get
            {
                return employeeID;
            }
            set
            {
                employeeID = value;
            }

        }
        public string employeeInformationToString()
        {
           // employeeID = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
            return (Convert.ToString(employeeID) + " " + fullName + " " + lastName + " " + Convert.ToString(salary));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  collection of `employee` in your form.

You just need simple `Linq` to find an employee for given employeeid.

```
var found = employee.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.EmployeeIDNum == employeeid);

if(found != null)
{
    // logic here.
   //  found.employeeInformationToString();

    listBox1.Items.Clear(); // check this if you want to clear.
    listBox1.Items.Add(found.employeeInformationToString());
}
```

So your complete search code should be something like...

```
private void sreachbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //// Need Some Thing Here

    int employeeid;

    if(int.TryParse(textbo1.Text, out employeeid)) // use your textbox name.
    {
        var found = employee.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.EmployeeIDNum == employeeid);

        if(found != null)
        {
            // logic here.
            found.employeeInformationToString()
        }
    }

}
```

**Update :**

Looks like you are not familiar with `Linq` , in this case try uing traditional looping.

```
private void sreachbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //// Need Some Thing Here

    int employeeid;

    if(int.TryParse(textbo1.Text, out employeeid))
    {
        Employee found= null;

        foreach(var emp in employee)
        {
            if(emp.EmployeeIDNum == employeeid)
            {
                found = emp;
                break;
            }
        }

        //var found = employee.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.EmployeeIDNum == employeeid);

        if(found != null)
        {
            // logic here.
            found.employeeInformationToString()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I GOT THIS Error A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter Project employee

Comment: i got this error now Use of unassigned local variable 'found' Project employee

Comment: just say `Employee found= null`

Comment: Now another error The name 'EmployeeIDNum' does not exist in the current context Project employee

Comment: But its exist in the class

Comment: ahh... I missed it. it should be `emp.EmployeeIDNum`

Comment: Now the code is not showing  error but still when I click on button no result what should I do sir

Comment: I am new to c# thats why I came here to get help

Comment: no problem, now you have found an employee what do you want to do? popup a message box or you want to show in textbox? what do you want to do?

Comment: then simply add it to the listbox, check the updated code.

Comment: Thank you very much sir its really worked you solved my problem  its really kind of you ...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
private void sreachbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int searchID = int.Parse(txtIdSearch.Text);
    // Need to handle if the user input is not a number..
    Employee[] employeeResults = employee.Where(e => e.employeeID == searchID).ToArray();
    // For possibility that your ID is not unique..
    // code to display results
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeResults .Length; i++)
    {
        string employeeString = employeeResults [i].employeeInformationToString() + "\r\n";

        listBox1.Items.Add(employeeString);

    }
 }
```

Comment: I got this error A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter Project employee